# recall data from a JSON file to a textarea after saving that input dynamically to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

HTML:

```
<label>Label: </label>
<br />
<input type="text" id="label" class="label"/><hr />
<label>Note Content: </label>
<br />
<textarea id="content"></textarea><hr />
<button id="saveBtn">SAVE</button><hr />
<div id="output">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(saveBtn).click(function(){
var noteLabel = $(label).val();
var noteContent = $(content).val();
var outputarea = $(output);
var info = [
 { "label":"John" , "content":"Doe" }];
$.each(info, function() {
    i=0;
    info[i].label = noteLabel;
    info[i].content = noteContent;
    outputarea.append('label: ' + info[i].label + '<br>content:' + info[i].content + '<button onclick="recallNote();">Recall</button><hr />');
    i++;
    function recallNote(){
        $(label).val(info[i].label); 
        $(content).val(info[i].content); 
    }
});
});
```

I am trying to get the function recallNote() to get the input box and textarea to change to the value of the text that is associated with the button. If you look at my JSFiddle you should be able to understand better.

When you enter text into the input box and textarea and then click the save button the text will get stored into a JSON object and then displayed in the output div.

Essentially i am trying to create a notepad web app so i can store notes and the recall button is suppsed to recall them back into the input box and textarea above so that the user can edit the note and label of the note.

Comment: Link to my JSFiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/ka05th30ry/tqCwr/30/

Comment: Is there a problem.....?

Comment: Yeah, previous to Phil's Answer, It would not recall the data back into the input box and textarea. It is now working just fine, but i nee to write a script for a delete button. new JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ka05th30ry/tqCwr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this JS:

```
var info = [{ "label":"John" , "content":"Doe" }];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(info, function(i, obj){
        $('#output').append('label: ' + obj.label + '<br>content:' + obj.content + '<button class="btn-recall" data-label="' + obj.label + '" data-content="' + obj.content + '">Recall</button><hr />');
    });

    $(document).on('mousedown keydown', '.btn-recall', function(){
        $('#label').val($(this).data('label')); 
        $('#content').val($(this).data('content')); 
    });

    $(document).on('mousedown keydown', '#saveBtn', function(){
        info.push({"label": $('#label').val(), "content": $('#content').val()});

        $('#output').append('label: ' + $('#label').val() + '<br>content:' + $('#content').val() + '<button class="btn-recall" data-label="' + $('#label').val() + '" data-content="' + $('#content').val() + '">Recall</button><hr />');
    });
});
```

I've updated the answer. Now when the page loads, it will add anything in your json array to the `output` div. When you click the `save` button, it will add it to the `output` div, and also the JSON array.

You can then click the recall button to repopulate the form.

**EDIT**

*How it works:*

The `info` variable is stored in the global scope (Outside of all functions). This makes it available within *all* functions (even the anonymous ones).

On the 3rd line, `$(document).ready(function(){`, this is where I've put all the functionality to recall, save and prepare the data.

The direct line below, line 4, is run as soon as the document has finished loading. This will loop through your JSON, using the `$.each()` function. It will then add a peice of HTML to the `output` div.

Whenever a new `recall` button is created, I've also added 2 `data` attributes to the button. `data-label` and `data-content`. These attributes stored the label and content for that particular field.

Back to the jQuery, on line 8, where is says `$(document).on('mousedown keydown', '.btn-recall'...`, this is binding an event to the recall button. Its saying, whenever you press this recall button, do this function. The function being called is:

```
function(){
    $('#label').val($(this).data('label')); 
    $('#content').val($(this).data('content')); 
}
```

The code within the `.val()` function `($(this).data('label'));` says to retrieve the data attribute `label` for the pressed button and insert it into the `label` text box. Likewise, the next line says to retrieve the `content` data attribute value and insert it into the content textarea.

The next part of the jQuery, binds an event to the `saveBtn` button. This function performs 2 actions. First of all it adds an element to the JSON array, using `info.push()`. `push()` will 'push' an element into an array.

The second action this function takes, is to append the label, content and recall button to the output div.

The important part of the jQuery, is that each recall button has the `data-label` and `data-content` attributes, as these are what store the label and content data for each recall button.

Once the button is pressed, all data associated with is can be obtained using the `.btn-recall` event.

**Saving the data**

There are a couple of ways to store the data.
If you want to do it in pure JS, there are also 2 ways. Storing data in a Cookie, and storing data in localStorage.

Both ways aren't great. Cookies only allow 4kb of data, and add to the page headers, which isn't great for performance. LocalStorage is a HTML5 thing, so you would have to rely on your visitors having modern web browsers.

**Cookies**

To save the data to a cookie, look at this plugin for jQuery: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie  change the '#saveBtn' function to this:

```
$(document).on('mousedown keydown', '#saveBtn', function(){
    info.push({"label": $('#label').val(), "content": $('#content').val()});

    $('#output').append('label: ' + $('#label').val() + '<br>content:' + $('#content').val() + '<button class="btn-recall" data-label="' + $('#label').val() + '" data-content="' + $('#content').val() + '">Recall</button><hr />');

    $.cookie("info", info);
}
```

And change the `$.each()` function to this:

```
$.each($.cookie('info'), function(i, obk){
    info.push({"label": obj.label, "content": obj.content });

    $('#output').append('label: ' + obj.label + '<br>content:' + obj.content + '<button class="btn-recall" data-label="' + obj.label + '" data-content="' + obj.content + '">Recall</button><hr />');
});
```

This would save the JSON to a cookie, which would be saved whenever the user refreshed the page.

Alternatively, you can do it using localStorage for HTML5 users:

```
localStorage.setItem('info', JSON.stringify(info));
```

and to retrieve:

```
info = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('info'));
```

Another method to store the data, which I would personally use, could be to pass the info json to AJAX, which would then pass it to a PHP page to save into a database, or into a session.

The database option is the best one to employ if you expect users to be away from your page for long periods of time, but still want to retrieve the data.

Comment: Thank you so much Phil!! I have been struggling to figure this out for almost a week. I tried using local storage, and arrays, and could not get it to work for the life of me. I cant thank yo enough man!

Comment: Also is there any chance you could explain how the button section works? or point me in a direction where i can learn about it?   <button class="btn-recall" data-label="' + obj.label + '" data-content="' + obj.content + '">Recall</button>

Comment: Is there a way to store the entered notes into the JSON so that when i reload the page the entered notes will not disappear?

Comment: Not a problem :) If It helped, please consider accepting the answer :) I'll update my answer with an explanation as to how it works, and how to store the JSON array.

Comment: Thanks again Phil! You did a phenomenal job explaining the button! Im pretty sure i understand the cookie method but for the local storage method can i just insert the two lines you stated above into my $.each function? or is it more involved than that? Also would it be easier to use PHP to do this or local storage? I know a little PHP from codecademy and a web development class but never went over saving to a database.

Comment: Using LocalStorage i can now save the notes and will remain after refreshing the browser but i am unable to figure out how to get them to delete. currently my delete function will only remove the element from the output div but i cant figure out how to remove the data associated with that button from localstorage. I also would like to be able to overwrite the note i am editing when i click the "save" button after hitting the "recall" button. I thought about using an if else to check if the text in the input and textarea changed but how would i overwrite the previous element? @Phil Cross

Comment: Finally solved the delete function. I still havent figured out how to overwrite a previous note after recalling it to the textarea though. :/